# electron-vue-vite not working after package?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, vuejs3

[Source Code](https://github.com/ZeronoFreya/vite-demo)

The error message is
`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

The compiled code contains `Object.defineProperty(exports,"__esModule",{value:!0})`

Found a solution by google: `<script> var exports = {}; </script>`

but `Cannot find module './Index.b211c312.js'`

```
│  index.html
└─_assets
        Index.b211c312.js
        index.fa062449.js
        style.032a3e7d.css
```

in `index.html`

```
<script type="module" src="./_assets/index.fa062449.js"></script>
```

in `index.fa062449.js`

```
require("./Index.b211c312.js")
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Update electron-vue-vite to the latest version, there is a fix!

https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron/issues/6#issuecomment-1144833465